# Java Netbeans Error Cannot find symbol, symbol: class out, location: class System, <identifier> expected, illegal start of type

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm getting an error in Netbeans in my driver class on this line:

```
System.out.print("Time waited is: " + (serializedTime - System.currentTimeMillis())/1000 + " secs.");
```

The error is:  "Cannot find symbol, symbol: class out, location: class System,  expected, illegal start of type.

```
import domain.PersistentObject;
import domain.PopulationRecord;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import utilities.MiniProj2Utilities;


    public class MiniProj2Driver {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Make sure that you develop your main() method with reduced code as shown below. 
        // Not the use of private static methods in the driver called from main() method.

        // Read the CSV file records into a list of PopulationRecord objects...
        List<PopulationRecord> popList = MiniProj2Utilities.getDataRecords();

        // Display the list contents and size...
        MiniProj2Utilities.displayRecordsFromList(popList);

        // Create and populate the PersistentObject...
        PersistentObject po = MiniProj2Utilities.getPersistentObject(popList);
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("./data/population-record.ser"));
            oos.writeObject(po);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

           long serializedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(po);

         try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Sleep Error");
        }
        try {
            ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("./data/population-record.ser"));
            PersistentObject po1 = (PersistentObject)oos.readObject();
        } catch (IOException ex) 
        {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        }
        }
        System.out.print("Time waited is: " + (serializedTime - System.currentTimeMillis())/1000 + " secs.");



    // Read the CSV file records into a list of PopulationRecord objects...
    private static List<PopulationRecord> getDataRecords() {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = null;
        List<PopulationRecord> list = new ArrayList<PopulationRecord>();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/NST_EST2011_ALLDATA.csv"));
            br.readLine(); // Remove header line from file...
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(",");
                //System.out.println(line);            
                PopulationRecord pr = new PopulationRecord(
                    tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3], tokens[4],
                    Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]), Integer.parseInt(tokens[6]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[7]), Long.parseLong(tokens[8]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[9]), Long.parseLong(tokens[10]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[11]), Long.parseLong(tokens[12]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[13]), Long.parseLong(tokens[14]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[15]), Long.parseLong(tokens[16]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[17]), Long.parseLong(tokens[18]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[19]), Long.parseLong(tokens[20]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[21]), Long.parseLong(tokens[22]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[23]), Long.parseLong(tokens[24]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[25]), Long.parseLong(tokens[26]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[27]), Long.parseLong(tokens[28]),
                    Long.parseLong(tokens[29]));
                list.add(pr);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MiniProj2Driver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MiniProj2Driver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return list;
    }

    // Display the list contents and size...
    private static void displayRecordsFromList(List<PopulationRecord> list) {
        for (PopulationRecord record : list) {
            System.out.println(record);
        }
        System.out.println("Population records processed: " + list.size() + list.get(9));

    }

    private static PersistentObject getPersistentObject(List<PopulationRecord> list) {
        PersistentObject po = new PersistentObject();
        po.setSerializedTime(new Date());
        po.setPopulationList(list);
        return po;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a brace in the wrong place. There are two braces in a row above the error.

Comment: Next time, rightclick in your code, select format (or press Alt-Shift-F).  Netbeans will properly format your code, and errors like this will be a lot easier to spot :-)

Comment: Thank you, Andrew Lazarus and fvu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is, your `System.out` statement is outside method.

```
  }
        System.out.print("Time waited is: " + (serializedTime - System.currentTimeMillis())/1000 + " secs.");
```

move it to inside the braces

```
        System.out.print("Time waited is: " + (serializedTime - System.currentTimeMillis())/1000 + " secs.");
  }
```

Comment: @Grafica: Glad it helped. Enjoy coding.

Comment: @Grafica: And one suggestion, make your code properly indented, which helps in avoiding all these issues.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not exactly enjoying it yet.

Comment: @Grafica: You will as you go, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class potpie {

    private int day   = 0;
    private int month = 0;
    private int year  = 0;

    public potpie(int d, int m, int y){
        day   = d;
        month = m;
        year  = y;

        /* 
        No error of symbol: class out --------> SINCE IT IS INSIDE METHOD
        */
        System.out.printf("This is today's date = %d %d %d", month, day, year);
    }
    /* 
    Cannot find symbol: class out     --------> SINCE IT IS OUTSIDE METHOD
    */
    System.out.printf("This is today's date     = %d %d %d", month, day, year);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic thing is Java works on Encapsulation i.e wrapping code and the data together, and thus the concept of having classes. Now to operate on the instance variables of the class, you can only do it by some method. Your l.o.c, i.e "System.out.print("your data");" is lying loosely in the body of the class and it has the instance variables of the class. Also as stated earlier, to operate on instance variables you can do so by using methods or constructors only and thus since this code is lying loosely and there is no method to invoke it, you get the error. So put it into the method as suggested by user Nambari above.