# Why does Java expect a class instead of a variable here?

Tags: java, netbeans

In the code below, Java displayed an error message for the second-to-last-line. It says "illegal start of type---cannot find symbol. symbol: class possibleFactor. location: class IsItAFactor--- identifier expected".

It seems to be saying that the problem is that there's no possibleFactor class, yet I defined possibleFactor as an integer variable. So why is it still expecting possibleFactor to be a class, and what can I do to fix this?

```
public class IsItAFactor{

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int n = input.nextInt();
   int possibleFactor;
   int Factor;

   for (possibleFactor = 1; possibleFactor <= n; possibleFactor++){
      if (n % possibleFactor == 0)
         possibleFactor = Factor;
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Netbeans Error Cannot find symbol, symbol: class out, location: class System, <identifier> expected, illegal start of type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424703/java-netbeans-error-cannot-find-symbol-symbol-class-out-location-class-syste)

Comment: @user2864740 I don't think this is a duplicate of the question linked. Although the questions share the common theme of not having things within a method, there seems to be a big difference in the level of knowledge between the two askers. I was more confused than the asker in that question, as I didn't even know what a method was or that I needed one. So I think the difference in skill level alone justifies leaving this open as a separate question- "You left a line out of your method" as opposed to "You need something called a method, and this is an example of what a method is."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your class you need to define a method to contain the logic / implementation. Here is an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IsItAFactor {

    private void doSomething() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int possibleFactor;
        int Factor = 0;

        for (possibleFactor = 1; possibleFactor <= n; possibleFactor++) {
            if (n % possibleFactor == 0) {
                possibleFactor = Factor;
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Never post links to code, always include the code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write the logic, within a method. You can have class level attributes, but logic should always go inside a method.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very new to programming and don't yet know what some of the terms like "method", "class", and "logic" really mean. All I know is how to define various kinds of variables within a class and make basic programs using them- can you give a more detailed explanation for a beginner like myself?

Comment: functions in java are called methods and properties are called attributes.

Comment: What are functions and properties?